# JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF stacktrace null is passed - how to solve this error

Tags: react-native

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        showPass: false,
    }
}

async signIn() {
    try {
        let response = await fetch(URI, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({

                email: this.state.username,
                password: this.state.password,

            })
        });
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        if (response.status = 200) {

            alert('ok');
        } else {
            //Handle error
            alert('failed')
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error " + error);
    }
}
```

**onPress={this.signIn.bind(this)} -> making to all bind on this pressed**

While testing this code I am getting this error. I used to response json as text and tried to catch the error but still the error is the same and using the responseJson error to call the error then it shows the output but while making a request to post on url. Why it gives this error?

Comment: it seems that it is problem with  async use. you  need to use await  fetch  to make it work properly

Comment: still the error is same

Comment: i have change the code and using the await and async but still having the same issue

Comment: The prblm was in api !!!! And nw its working